# Webpack+Babeljs cannot transpile ES6

Tags: webpack, vue.js, babeljs

I am building a javascript web application using vue-cli.

I noticed there is some `const` keywords in the compiled javascript code. And the browser said `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode`

The compiled code looks like:

```
"use strict";
eval("/*blabla*/ const xxx ...");
```

My babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
```

The babel-loader configuration file is like:

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
  },
```

Comment: What is result of `resolve('src')`?

Comment: @SharikovVladislav it's `myProjectPath/src`, the directory where all my source code resides